# admob ads show on 5.0 devices and not on 6.0 own device

Tags: admob

I have weird problem. My admob ads are showing normally on 5.0 two tablets and when i test it on my lenovo a700 6.0 android it returns error code 3 
Error : ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL from ad listener below

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_banner_id" />
```

=========================================

```
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int error) {
            mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

That just means that there is no ad available for that device, at that place and that time. There is nothing wrong here.